# How to safely handle notifying a listener of state or an exception without ambiguity?

Tags: java, exception, listener

I'm looking at reworking a listener interface to remove null objects in an effort to try and make the API safer to use. It is currently designed as such:

```
@Override
public void acceptPerformed(
   AcceptEvent event,
   Throwable exception)
{
}
```

It's a simple interface where if `exception == null` then `event != null` and vice-versa. This is pretty clean and simple.

To eliminate the passing of null to this listener I've considered some alternatives but all it seems to do is move the goal post. For example, wrapping each object in an `Optional`:

```
@Override
public void acceptPerformed(
   AcceptEvent event)
{
   if (!event.isAccepted()) {
      event.getException().get()...

      // Notify the UI of failed accept

      return;
   }

   event.getEvent().get()...

   // Do something
}
```

In this example I don't provide an alternative object because none is acceptable. Even though I could provide my own runtime error, the listener contract is such that it should not ever throw one. But in this instance I feel like I'm just moving the `NullPointerException` to a potential `NoSuchElementException`. Maybe it eliminates the ambiguity of whether the objects passed could be null by explicitly wrapping as an `Optional` but I don't think this is much of an improvement.

I considered passing an object where I could check is `AcceptEvent instanceof AcceptEventExceptionally` but again, this this just moves to a potential `ClassCastException`.

The only solution I can think of to guarantee that all objects provided to a listener are well formed and don't require nulls, optionals, or casts, is to have separate listeners for the success and error conditions. This will double the number of listeners and also make the listener logic more difficult to handle.

Are there any patterns I can apply to this to provide a safer listener than the ones I've listed above?

The action which triggers the accept event can throw an I/O exception so there is no guarantee that it will always succeed. The I/O loop is running in a separate thread and is notifying the main thread of events through listeners. Here is an example implementation:

```
while (running) {
   try {
      // Do some I/O things
   }
   catch (IOException ex) {
      for (AcceptListener l : listeners)
         l.acceptPerformed(new AcceptEvent(ex));

      continue;
   }
}

for (AcceptListener l : listeners)
   l.acceptPerformed(new AcceptEvent(someObject));
```

Comment: How is the listener used, i.e. how does the event-generating code look like?

Comment: Thanks. Intuitively, I would not use the same listener for handling exceptions; the listener would only be used (as its name implies) when the accept was actually performed. The exception handling would be done somewhere further up the call stack, or by a separate handler; this of course depends on your architecture etc.

Comment: The accept action is happening in a separate thread so I need some way of notifying the main thread that an accept failed. In this case, it's an open socket that may receive many separate connections over its lifespan.

Comment: Not sure why two separate methods would make things more difficult. You simply make your current method private, and make the two public methods call it as it is now, if that logic is easier for you to write.

Comment: It's not just a single method. It double all methods which handle these listeners. There are now two private lists, four methods (add/remove x2), and two methods to override for handling each. This is a lot of additional code. But maybe it's just necessary given the circumstances?